# How to remove HTML tags in Vim?

Tags: html, vim

Considering a text like

```
<p>In this article, using <code>ffmpeg </code>I am going to
 show you just how easy it is to add a red hue to an image</p>
```

I want to remove the `<code>` and `</code>` tags only. I tried:

```
 vnoremap <silent> rt :s/<[^>]*>//g<CR>:noh<CR>
```

but this will remove all tags in current line even if the the only highlighted part is `<code>ffmpeg </code>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove one tag at a time, you can use the built-in `a<` text object which operates on an angle-bracket delimited area. Two `da<`s on the tags will remove the opening and closing tag, respectively.

In fact, I would just jump to "code", remove the tag and repeat:

```
/code<CR>da<n.
```

The reason why the `:substitute` command does not work as expected is because it works on *lines*, not the visual selection. You can use the `\%V` marker to constrain it to the visual area like this:

```
:s/\%V<[^>]*>//g
```

or (using non-greedy matching):

```
:s/\%V<.\{-}>//g
```

This will remove the `<code>` and `</code>` tags only but leave "ffmpeg" in the buffer.
See [`:help \%V`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25V).

Note that this will only operate on the current line so a line break in the wrong place may remove the starting but not the closing tag.

To remove both the tags and anything inside, you can use the `it` for *inner tag* and `at` for *a tag* text objects. Placing the cursor anywhere on `<code>...</code>` and pressing `dat` will remove both the opening and the closing code tags as well as anything inside.
See [`:help at`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#at) for more information. Text objects (as these are called) are incredibly useful and they can all be found in [`:help text-objects`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#text-objects).

This can be used to remove only the tags by yanking everything inside the tags, removing everything and putting back the first yank. With the cursor inside the tags, do:

```
yitdat"0P
```

Here `yit` yanks inside tags (implicitly to register `0`), `dat` deletes the tags and everything inside and `"0P` puts the contents of register `0` before the cursor. The big advantage is that this will also work across lines and honor nested tags.

For the occasional tag removal, I'd stick with `da<` as written above. If stripping tags comes up frequently in your work, you may consider creating a mapping for the commands above:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>rt yitdat"0P
```

Comment: thanks the da< is great, no need for the mapping or anything.

Comment: @NeoMosaid glad I could help. I added a link to `:help text-objects`. They are useful and it never hurts to refresh one's knowledge about them.

Comment: Hi @Friedrich - you said "built-in `a<` motion"... but that's a text object, I think?  (As mentioned in the comment about `:help text-objects` I think?)

Comment: @m_mlvx it's both. Type `:help text-objects` and you'll find yourself in a file `motions.txt`. Text objects are motions (although they cannot be used to move the cursor which is a little bit paradox). The idea seems to be that they move the cursor *over* an area. AFAIK, first there was `dw` and this was extended by `daw`, hence the classification as motions. Ironically, I don't like the two terms being used interchangeably and I fell into just that trap. I'll edit to reduce the confusion.